# Using BeautifulSoup for web scraping: ValueError obtained

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following error:

```
ValueError at /scrape/

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/scrape/
Django Version: 2.2.17
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Exception Location: c:\Users\toshiba\Desktop\newsscraper\news\views.py in scrape, line 32
Python Executable:  C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['c:\\Users\\toshiba\\Desktop\\newsscraper',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I am trying to scrape news articles from guardian.ng, but it seems to keep giving me an error.

This is my views.py file:

```
# import all necessary modules
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
from news.models import Headline

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

# new function news_list()
def news_list(request):
    headlines = Headline.objects.all()[::-1]
    context = {
        'object_list': headlines,
    }
    return render(request, "news/home.html", context)


# the view function scrape()
def scrape(request):
  session = requests.Session()
  session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
  # This HTTP header will tell the server information about the client. We are using Google bots for that purpose. 
  # # When our client requests anything on the server, the server sees our request coming as a Google bot.
  url = "https://www.guardian.ng/"
  content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
  # We create a soup object where we pass the HTML page. Alongside the HTML page, we also pass HTML parser as a parameter.
  soup = BSoup(content, "html.parser")
  # in the news object, we return the <div> of a particular class. We selected this class through webpage inspection.
  News = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"headline"}) 

  for article in News:
    main = dict(article.find_all('a'))# we can iterate over soup objects. 
    # In the for loop, the main variable will hold the link to the origin webpage. 
    # The main attribute gets the anchor tag. Since, the <div>s returned only have one <a>tag, we get most of our work done here.
    # The <a> tag contains title and href of the original link.
    link = main['href']
    image_src = str(main.find('img')['srcset']).split(" ")[-4] # srcset attribute contains various sizes of images...
    title = main['title']

    # saving the data to the database
    new_headline = Headline()
    new_headline.title = title
    new_headline.url = link
    new_headline.image = image_src
    new_headline.save()
  return redirect("../")
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Is that the entire error message/output?

Comment: Yes. That's all of it.